# Create JSON in PHP with multiple levels

Tags: php, json

I need to create json with multiple levels via PHP.

```
{
    "accident": {
        "dateTime": "2015-08-08T16:12:08",
        "desc": "string"
    },
    "calculationInput": {
        "idBlockCodes": [
            {
                "code": 51,
                "value": 1
            }
        ],
        "wageRates": {
            "labourRate1": 10,
            "labourRate2": 11,
            "labourRate3": 22,
            "labourRate4": 33,
            "labourRateD": 44,
            "paintRate": 55
        }
    },
    "caseNumber": "F4Q",
    "vehicle": {
        "adminData": {
            "firstRegDate": "2015-07-08",
            "numberPlate": "MI214AF"
        },
        "identification": {
            "vin": "VF7S6NFZF56215577"
        },
        "owner": {
            "city": "Praha",
            "country": "CZE",
            "email": "mail@mail.com",
            "name": "Fero Taraba",
            "phone": "777111222",
            "phone2": "999555333",
            "postCode": "07101",
            "street": "Kukureliho 18"
        }
    }
}
```

I actuyltry this and it's possible for me to create single level json, with other words:

```
$data = array (
        "caseNumber" =>"F4Q"    
        );
```

and then just easy:

```
$data_json= json_encode($data);
```

But can someone explain me how can I do this second or even 3th level tree to convert to JSON?

I will really appriciate your help guys. Thanks

**EDIT**:
Most of the answers really lead me right way, only problem now is this part:

```
  "idBlockCodes": [
                {
                    "code": 51,
                    "value": 1
                }
            ],
```

where there is [ ] which represent some list of blockCodes. Any idea what to do with this ? :)

Comment: is that [] what you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

What is your question exactly?

You can create a array and then just encoding it to json?

```
$data = array(
    'Key 1' => array(
         'Key 2 - Key 1' => array(
              'Key 3 - Key 1' => array()
          )
    )
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you Youri, but I afriad this will not fight correctly with this part:
        `"idBlockCodes": [
            {
                "code": 51,
                "value": 1
            }
        ],`

Answer (score 1):

Just use associative arrays

```
$data = array (
        "caseNumber" =>"F4Q",    
        "vehicle" => array (
            "adminData"=>
                     array(
                      "firstRegDate"=> "2015-07-08",
                       "numberPlate"=> "MI214AF"
                     ),
              "identification" =>
                      array(
                      "vin"=> "VF7S6NFZF56215577"
                      )      
            )
        );
```

print out

```
{"caseNumber":"F4Q","vehicle":{"adminData":{"firstRegDate":"2015-07-08","numberPlate":"MI214AF"},"identification":{"vin":"VF7S6NFZF56215577"}}}
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answer it definitley make sense, but may I ask what to do with  [ ] this kind of brackets? :)
Please check my edit in question

Answer (score 1):

Use associative Arrays:

```
$data = array (
    "caseNumber" =>"F4Q",    
    "vehicle" => array (
        "adminData"=>
                 array(
                  "firstRegDate"=> "2015-07-08",
                   "numberPlate"=> "MI214AF"
                 ),
          "identification" =>
                  array(
                  "vin"=> "VF7S6NFZF56215577"
                  )      
        )
    );

echo json_encode($data)
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answer it definitley make sense, but may I ask what to do with  [ ] this kind of brackets? :)
Please check my edit in question

Comment: I think that is a notAssociative array in php? Always avoided such lists in JSON Arrays..

Comment: thanks for advise I give you thumb up for answer, anyway It's not my choose how JSON have to looks like, because this is what REST service expect I just need to make it in PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

you get your brackets by putting an additional array around your object.

```
$data = array("idBlockCodes" => array(
            array(
                "code" => 51,
                "value" => 1
            )
        )
  );

 print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Dispite the fact it's other brackets this time? [ instead of { ? :)

Answer (score 0):

For you to convert all of your data to array:

You must first use `json_encode()`;

```
   $a = json_encode($yourData);
```

And then decode it:

```
   $b = json_decode($a, true);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($b); //print it
```

It displays associated arrays with it